# Merge two dataframe, keep the past data, and updating new value based on column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have an Existing DataFrame looks like this,

**DF_1**

| Hour | Value_1 | Value_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 13:00 | 20 | 30 |
| 14:00 | 20 | 30 |
| 15:00 | 120 | 140 |
| 16:00 | 125 | 145 |
| 17:00 | 130 | 135 |
| 18:00 | 20 | 20 |

and I have an Updating DataFrame, looks like,

**DF_2**

| Hour | Value_1 | Value_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 15:00 | 200 | 240 |
| 16:00 | 225 | 255 |
| 17:00 | 260 | 275 |

What I want to have is,

**DF_FINAL**

| Hour | Value_1 | Value_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 13:00 | 20 | 30 |
| 14:00 | 20 | 30 |
| 15:00 | 200 | 240 |
| 16:00 | 225 | 255 |
| 17:00 | 260 | 275 |
| 18:00 | 20 | 20 |

I already tried by using merge, join, concat, and even Updating(), and also combine_first().
But I didn't get what I wanted.

Would anyone please explain the correct way?

Comment: Assuming Hour the index: `df_final = df1.copy(), df_final.update(df2)` or `df_final = df2.combine_first(df1)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas: updating column values when merging DataFrames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37142896/pandas-updating-column-values-when-merging-dataframes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate both dataframes then keep only last occurence of each hour then sort your dataframe:

```
out = (pd.concat([df1, df2])
         .drop_duplicates('Hour', keep='last')
         .sort_values('Hour', ignore_index=True))
print(out)

# Output
    Hour  Value_1  Value_2
0  13:00       20       30
1  14:00       20       30
2  15:00      200      240
3  16:00      225      255
4  17:00      260      275
5  18:00       20       20
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible answer:

```
update_dict1 = dict(zip(df2['Hour'], df2['Value_1']))
update_dict2 = dict(zip(df2['Hour'], df2['Value_2']))

df3 = df1.copy()


df3['Value_1'] = df1.Hour.map(update_dict1)
df3['Value_2'] = df1.Hour.map(update_dict2)

mask = df3.Value_1.isna()

df3.loc[mask, 'Value_1'] = df1.loc[mask]['Value_1']
df3.loc[mask, 'Value_2'] = df1.loc[mask]['Value_2']

df3
```

Output:

```
    Hour  Value_1  Value_2
0  13:00     20.0     30.0
1  14:00     20.0     30.0
2  15:00    200.0    240.0
3  16:00    225.0    255.0
4  17:00    260.0    275.0
5  18:00     20.0     20.0
```

##### **Edit**

The  solutions suggested by @mozway in the comments are the shortest way to update values as you showed:

```
df1 = df1.set_index('Hour')
df2 = df2.set_index('Hour')
```

Using `.update()`:

```
df_final = df1.copy()
df_final.update(df2)
```

Or `.combine_first()`:

```
df_final = df2.combine_first(df1)
df_final
```

Output:

```
       Value_1  Value_2
Hour                   
13:00       20       30
14:00       20       30
15:00      200      240
16:00      225      255
17:00      260      275
18:00       20       20
```